# edited HTML wrapper template in Flash Builder 4 but my changes do not appear

Tags: html, templates, flexbuilder, wrapper

I edited the  index.template.html file, adding a script block to the HEAD section, but my changes are not there when running the project in Debug mode or in Run mode.

I'm using SDK 4.0 with the public release of beta 2 (not using nightlies yet) and modified the only template found in this folder:

\Adobe\Adobe Flash Builder Beta 2\sdks\4.0.0\templates\swfobject

Am I editing the wrong template? The only others I see are for 3.4.1.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to change the template for all your future projects? I'm assuming you just want to change the template for one projects.

Modify the that gets generated in your project /html-template/index.template.html

Comment: Thanks for the help. I would like to add this functionality to all projects but as long as I can add it to each project at a time, not a big deal. BTW, I'd like to "accept" your answer but I'm not seeing an Accept button anywhere. I've emailed tech support about the lack of an Accept button.

Comment: In that case you edited the right file the first time. But for existing projects you made need to delete the html-template folder in your project and recreate it. In Flash Builder you'll get an error in the Problems panel after you delete the folder that you tell you you can right-click on it to regenerate the files.